# disable key combination (keyboard shortcuts) in vbnet

Tags: vb.net, keyboard-shortcuts

i'm currently working on a security program and i need to temporarily disable some key combinations using vbnet. Key combinations such as: Ctrl-Alt-Delete, Alt-Tab, Alt-Esc, Win Keys, Alt Keys, Esc.

i badly need you help guys. thanks!

Comment: Look for USB scissors so you can cut the keyboard cable.  The only way to temporarily disable Ctrl+Alt+Del. A program that tries to disable these keys is not often called a "security program".

Comment: You can't disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, and it's that way for a reason. If you need to do that, you're not writing a "security program". Voting to close.

Comment: My high school had software that blocked Ctrl+Alt+Del for 'security' reasons installed on the lab PCs.  I'm not saying this guy has a legit reason for asking the Q, but I swear, I've seen that very feature before.

Comment: It can be done with the group policy editor.  That's not temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable and enable CTRL+ALT+DEL on demand (at least, you could.  I haven't tried this in Windows 7).  Take a look at the link below

**SystemParametersInfo Function**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx

I can see why some people are hesitant to answer this question (and that's why I'm hesitant to post usable lines of code); but I do believe there are legit ways to use this (and clearly, Microsoft agrees because they expose this functionality through their APIs).

I have seen this done in professional/commercial software.

EDIT:  I don't know whether or not this approach will disable the other keyboard short-cuts; but it should work for CTRL+ALT+DEL